# c++ random number generator that allows user to choose range

Tags: c++, random, numbers, range, generator

I have to come up with a random number generator where it will generate 5 random numbers that are within a range of two number entered by the user.  Example:  User first enters 1 then 10. Random numbers generated could be 2,3,4,5,8.  I can get it to give me 1 random number 5 times, but not 5 different random numbers.  Please see below.  Any help is appreciated.  Thanks!

```
#include <iostream>
#include <cstdlib>
#include <ctime>
using namespace std;

int main ()
{
        int num1, num2, randNum, seed;


        cout << "enter number 1.\n";
        cin >> num1;
        cout << "enter number 2.\n";
        cin >> num2;

seed = num1 - num2;
randNum = rand() % seed + 1;

        cout << randNum << "\n";
        cout << randNum << "\n";
        cout << randNum << "\n";
        cout << randNum << "\n";
        cout << randNum << "\n";

return 0;
}
```

Comment: try to set time, to get different values each time you lauch the program. srand (time(NULL));

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`randNum` isn't modified each time you call `cout` so it always displays the same value. If you want it to work you need to use a loop like this

```
for(int i=0;i<5;i++){
    randNum = rand() % seed + num2;
    cout << randNum << "\n";
}
```

The second mistake was using `+1` instead of `+num2` so this will generate a number within the range you expect, assuming `num2` is smaller than `num1`.

There is one more thing you should consider is the name of your variable `seed`. A seed is what you use to initialize a random number generator. Here your variable is just here to express a range. To get different results when you run your program every time, you need to initialize rand with something, for example with this: `srand(time(0));`

Comment: " I can get it to give me 1 random number 5 times, but not 5 different random numbers." I wanted to answer to that part of the question. I actually didn't see he also made a mistake on the minimal value.

Comment: This is great thank you!  But what can i do if num2 is larger than num1?  We havent covered loops yet so i dont think i can or am expected to use them use them for this.

Comment: If you don't want to use loops you can just copy/paste the two lines one after another (ugly but it works). You can use a condition to check and switch for example: `if(num2>num1){int temp=num1; num1=num2; num2=temp;}`

Answer (score 2):

You're generating one random number and then printing it five times. The code `rand() % seed + 1` is what generates the value. You save that one value in `randNum` and print it five times. You could instead run the code `rand() % seed + 1` multiple times to get multiple values.

---

You're not using the word 'seed' correctly in this context. A seed, in the context of a pseudo random number generator, is an initial state for the generator. Seeding the pRNG that is used by `rand()` is done by passing a seed value to `srand()` ('s' stands for seed).

---

Anyway, you shouldn't use `rand()`. Instead use the C++ `<random>` library. Using this library you can very easily create values in a user defined range.

The basic method of producing random values with `<random>` uses two components: A source of 'randomness', the pRNG, which I'll call an engine, and an object that takes randomness from the engine and uses it to produce values randomly in a particular range.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <random>

int main() {
    int min, max;
    std::cout << "enter number 1.\n";
    std::cin >> min;
    std::cout << "enter number 2 (greater than number 1).\n";
    std::cin >> max;

    std::uniform_int_distribution<> make_number_in_range(min, max);
    std::mt19937 engine;

    std::cout << make_number_in_range(engine) << ' ';
    std::cout << make_number_in_range(engine) << ' ';
    std::cout << make_number_in_range(engine) << ' ';
    std::cout << make_number_in_range(engine) << ' ';
    std::cout << make_number_in_range(engine) << ' ';
}
```

> enter number 1. `1`
>   enter number 2 (greater than number 1). `6`
>   5 2 5 6 2

In this code, the values are generated by the code `make_number_in_range(engine)`. Note that this code is run multiple times to produce multiple values.

Also notice that instead of having to manipulate the results of `rand()` with some aritmetic operations you simply tell `make_number_in_range` the range you want. Your original code is performing the wrong arithmetic, but this code doesn't have to worry about it.

---

Neither your original program nor the program I show above will produce different output each time it is run with a particular input. This is because the random number generator always starts in the same initial state. (However, different implementations can show different results, so you may not see the same numbers as I show above when you try the range I used.)

In order to get different results each time the program is run, you need to seed the pRNG differently each time. In order to do that you can update the program like so:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <random>

int main() {
    int min, max;
    std::cout << "enter number 1.\n";
    std::cin >> min;
    std::cout << "enter number 2 (greater than number 1).\n";
    std::cin >> max;

    std::uniform_int_distribution<> make_number_in_range(min, max);

    std::random_device r;
    std::seed_seq seed{r(), r(), r(), r(), r(), r(), r(), r()};
    std::mt19937 engine(seed);

    std::cout << make_number_in_range(engine) << ' ';
    std::cout << make_number_in_range(engine) << ' ';
    std::cout << make_number_in_range(engine) << ' ';
    std::cout << make_number_in_range(engine) << ' ';
    std::cout << make_number_in_range(engine) << ' ';
}
```

Comment: I agree you solution is better but is probably too complicated for someone who seem to just getting started with coding.

Comment: @meneldal Eh, the seeding is more complicated, but notice that it's simpler to specify the desired range. I would recommend beginners use `uniform_int_distribution` over trying to compute their own distributions from `rand()`.

Comment: @meneldal: notice too that the identifier "seed" is not used for a seed value in the original code, and the next inevitable question is "why does my program produce the same series of numbers every time, when they're supposed to be random"... then comes `srand(time(0));` (and an extra header) and explaining it must only be done once per program execution, before `rand()` is called; pretty soon using `rand()` is looking more and more complicated too....

Comment: I did see that as well and I should have edited my answer when I noticed it indeed. I agree it is a very bad name for this variable.